# Enumerator vs Iterator in scala and java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, loops

What is the difference between Enumerator and Iterator? Per my understanding `Enumerator` is not a fancy alias for `enum` in Java. Rather, it seems to be a traversal technique similar to an `Iterator`. So is anyone able to compare and contrast `Enumerator` and `Iterator`? Also, I see a usage in `Play` as

```
val data = getDataStream
val dataContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromStream(data)
```

EDIT:

I am inclined to think that `Enumerator` gives us actual chunks of data, whereas `Iterator` gives us pointers to data that is already chunked, such as a list. But I am not convinced that that's the case.

Comment: I look for `Enumerator` in java and all that turns up is `Enumeration` (whose javadoc clearly states that it has the same functions of `Iteration`). Can point a link to the javadoc?

Comment: @foampile you're confusing [`Enumerator`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Enumerators) with `Enumeration` which are the different things

Comment: `Enumeration` is essentially deprecated nowadays; `Iterator` is its replacement.

Answer (score 9):

`Enumerator` is a [Play class](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Enumerators), not a Java or Scala one.

It is part of the [`Iteratee`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Iteratees) I/O-handling which Play provides. Iteratees are an interesting beast -- on one hand, it "pushes" data to the handler, instead of relying to the handler to pull data, and, therefore, has better performance. On the *other* hand, it allows the handler to control when the flow should be stopped. Finally, one can compose iteratees so that different iteratees are responsible for different parts of the input (say, one to receive HTTP headers, other to receive its body) as well as chaining them so low level iteratees can do a pre-processing which is then fed to higher level iteratees.

There's plenty of material on them, avail yourself to it.

It is *not* related in any way to iterators or enumerations.

Comment: Actually Java does use Enumerator. One place I can recall seeing one is in the `Hashtable` class.

Comment: @user1612593 but it is not public API (the class is hidden completely inside Hashtable).

Comment: @user1612593 you mean `Enumeration` (which is the older "version" of `Iterator`).

Comment: @Javier [not necessary](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.Enumerator), but yes, in fact it implements Enumeration

Comment: @user1612593 This is a class with the name `Enumerator`, but it isn't related to the Play `Enumerator`.