# Scala Play `Enumerators`: push or pull?

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

I'm really having trouble understanding the fundamental purposes for Play's `Iteratee`s and `Enumerator`s.

I've read

- [Understand Play2 Iteratees for Normal Humans](http://mandubian.com/2012/08/27/understanding-play2-iteratees-for-normal-humans/)
- [Iteratees](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/Iteratees)
- [Enumerators](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/Enumerators)

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032753/1212596) to find that instead of relying on a pulling model, like `InputStream`, it uses a pushing model.

> Iteratees are an interesting beast -- on one hand, it "pushes" data to the handler, instead of relying to the handler to pull data, and, therefore, has better performance. On the other hand, it allows the handler to control when the flow should be stopped.

But then Play's documentation on `Iteratee`s says

> Or more generally enumerating a `java.io.InputStream` using `Enumerator.fromStream`. It is important to note that input won’t be read until the iteratee this Enumerator is applied on is ready to take more input.

Wait....so what is going on?

Does the data get pushed by the `Enumerator` or pulled by the `Iteratee`? (i.e. who decides when it is time to calculate more data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both. It is entirely non-blocking for both ends of the stream.

The `Enumerator` doesn't push any data until the `Iteratee` is ready to receive it, and it doesn't push any more data until the `Iteratee` signals it is ready for more. At the same time, the `Enumerator` can take as long as it wants to push data. Neither process will block on the other.

This method, on `Iteratee`, is critical to understanding how it works:

```
abstract def fold[B](folder: (Step[E, A]) ⇒ Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[B]
```

This is the sole abstract method in `Iteratee`, the only one that must be implemented. All the rest of the methods are defined in terms of `fold`. When an `Enumerator` is applied to an `Iteratee`, it invokes this method, providing the `folder` which is effectively a callback. Once the `Iteratee` is ready, it invokes `folder` providing the state it is currently in, `Cont` if it can receive more data, `Done` if it doesn't need any more, or `Error` if something has gone wrong. And because `folder` returns a `Future`, it can take as long as it needs to provide further input if the `Iteratee` is in the `Cont` state.